How to center caption under underlined text
I'm using ulem package to underline text. That's my setup:
\usepackage{ulem}
\setlength\ULdepth{1.5pt}

\noindent Student  {\uline{Meow Meow \hfill} \\[-.3\baselineskip] {\centering \footnotesize full name}}

That's what I get:

Full name should be centred relative to underlined text.

It helps the community a lot if you post a complete MWE instead of just a fragment.

You don't want uline.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\filldata}[4][\columnwidth]{%
  % %1 = optional width, default \columnwidth
  % #2 = header
  % #3 = explanation
  % #4 = data (may be empty)
  \noindent\settowidth{\dimen0}{#2:\ }%
  \raisebox{2pt}{#2:\ }%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}w{l}{\dimeval{#1-\dimen0}}@{}}
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{2pt}{#4}}\hrulefill \\[-1ex]
  \scriptsize\hfil #3
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\filldata{Student}{full name}{Meow Meow}

\bigskip

\filldata[5cm]{Birthdate}{dd/mm/yyyy}{}\hfill
\filldata[5cm]{Town}{town name}{}\quad

\end{document}


In a different way, using a suggestion in comment.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\filldata}[4][\columnwidth]{%
  % %1 = optional width, default \columnwidth
  % #2 = header
  % #3 = explanation
  % #4 = data (may be empty)
  \noindent\settowidth{\dimen0}{#2:\ }%
  \mbox{#2:\ }%
  \begingroup\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
  \makebox[\dimeval{#1-\dimen0}][l]{#4} \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{\scriptsize#3}
  \end{tabular}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\filldata{Student}{full name}{Meow Meow}

\bigskip

\filldata[5cm]{Birthdate}{dd/mm/yyyy}{}\hfill
\filldata[5cm]{Town}{town name}{}\quad

\end{document}



Thank you! Could this function be written without passing header? Also, would it work as an element in tabularray table?

@Intolighter You should give better specifications in your question.

It's not necessary right now, I just asked.

Could the width of underlines be equal to the width of specified text, as I wanted in my code snippet? My inputs will always be with data. I need this as soon as possible.

With code:
\filldata[5cm]{Birthdate}{dd/mm/yyyy}{}%
\filldata{Town}{town name}{}

Second input goes beyond the boundary.

@egreg Is there a particular reason to put \hfill #3\hfill\hspace*{0pt} rather than \hfil #3?

@pascal974 No.

Weird answer while announcing array (tabular) as the key, then using size calculations and \hrulefill. I'd say a two-column tabular, use \cline{2-2}, and center the under-tag within the same column using \multicolumn{1}{c}.

@DonaldArseneau Since I want to control the global size, measuring is necessary.

You can simply add a \hfill before the text.
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{ulem}
\setlength\ULdepth{1.5pt}

\begin{document}
\noindent Student {\uline{\hfill Meow Meow \hfill} \\[-.3\baselineskip]
{\centering \footnotesize full name}}

\end{document}


Too bad \centering doesn't work as a declaration for a part within a paragraph. Moreover, you probably want to center the date below the blank. So I'd change the last line to \phantom{Student }{\footnotesize \hfill full name\hfill}\par. (Untested.)
